# Is it possible to make a var class?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a multiplayer game with multiple classes. The script that runs the server needs to reference scripts on these different classes, without knowing which class the player is until the player chooses. I wanted to try to reference the script as a var.

For example

```
var script; 

if (class == class1)
{
    script = class1Script; 
}
else if (class == class2)
{
    script = class2Script;
}

script.function();
```

However var is method only. My current fix is having the different class functions in one script and giving the classes a number. So

```
start()
{
    int classNumber;
    if (class1)
    {
        class = 1; 
    } 
    else if (class2)
    {
        class = 2;
    }
}

update()
{
    switch(classNumber)
        case(1): function1 
        case(2): function2 
}
```

which works but seems very inefficient, especially with a lot of classes.

Comment: All the classes should chare a common interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `fuction` on your instance assumes there **is** such a method. So if none of your condition matches, you'd get an error as `fuction` doesn't exist. The best way to ensure this is by creating a common interface all your classes have to implement:

```
IMyInterface script; 

if (condition1)
{
    script = new Class1Script(); 
}
else if (condition2)
{
    script = new Class2Script();
}

script.DoSomething();
```

with:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

and:

```
class Class1Script : IMyInterface { ...}
class Class2Script : IMyInterface { ...}
```

You can also use a common abstract base-class if you have some common logic between all your actual inheriting classes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though Interfaces would be suitable in your case.

You should define an interface for your classes to implement, for example:

```
public interface IPlayer {
   void Update();
}
```

```
public class PlayerType1 : IPlayer { }
public class PlayerType2 : IPlayer { }
```

The interface will define a contract that your classes promise to implement, so you can safely call the methods it exposes without knowing (or caring) what the underlying class actually is:

```
IPlayer player; 

if (condition) {
    player = new PlayerType1();
} else {
    player = new PlayerType2();
}

player.Update();
```